# Save tensors as images in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, back-projection

This might be a simple question. I am just trying to do radon transform of an image and save it using functions in TensorFlow. But the result is not right. I know I can use plt.imsave() to save the image correctly, but I want to know how to do it in TensorFlow.

I am new to TensorFlow and thank you for your help.

[This is the `shepp-logan.jpg` image I use. It is a grayscale image with size 64*64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4llqq.jpg)

[This is the saved image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpDc9.jpg)

Here is my code.

```
from skimage.transform import radon,iradon
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

sess = tf.Session()
img = plt.imread('shepp-logan.jpg')
theta = np.linspace(0., 180., max(img.shape), endpoint=False)
sinogram = radon(img, theta=theta, circle=True)
sinogram = tf.cast(sinogram, tf.uint8)
sinogram = tf.expand_dims(sinogram, -1)
sinogram = tf.image.encode_jpeg(sinogram, quality=100, format='grayscale')
writer = tf.write_file('test_sinogram.jpg', sinogram)
sess.run(writer)
```

Comment: Do you want to specifical save it or just view it and save in a tf-format?

Comment: @Lau It would be best if I can save it specifically. But how do I view it?

Comment: You can view it with tensorbard (tf.summary.image). Its late, I'll write you tomorow a detailed answer ;)

Comment: please include a functional example next time, you were just missing two lines and some proper indentation ... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the function radon returns values way too high for tensorflow.
Tensorflow wants values between 0 and 255 (`uint8`) per channel.

I didn't look why that is, but I did a quick test after looking at the values in `sinogram` and decided to divide by `np.max(sinogram)` and the result looks much closer to what you expect I believe :)

```
from skimage.transform import radon,iradon
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

sess = tf.Session()
img = plt.imread('shepp-logan.jpg')
theta = np.linspace(0., 180., max(img.shape), endpoint=False)
sinogram = radon(img, theta=theta, circle=True)

# scaling the values here
sinogram = 255*sinogram/np.max(sinogram)

sinogram = tf.cast(sinogram, tf.uint8)
sinogram = tf.expand_dims(sinogram, -1)
sinogram = tf.image.encode_jpeg(sinogram, quality=100, format='grayscale')
writer = tf.write_file('test_sinogram.jpg', sinogram)
sess.run(writer)
```

As for tensorboard, which I recommend you use, you have to use tf.summary.image: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/image

And here is a guide for tensorboard: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/summaries_and_tensorboard